# Override DbContext SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-mapping

I use EF 4.3.1 I need adding a Default Value of an entity at the moment of saving.

At the moment I'm using SaveChanges() and it works.

As you can see from the code I use `ChangeTracker.Entries<Option>()` where `Option` rappresent a specifc DataType.

I would like to know if is possible and  how to write a more generic version of ChangeTracker.Entries something like `ChangeTracker.Entries<t>()` so it can check all type of entities in my Model, as you can see in my specif case I have a NoteInternal property on many classes

```
      public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        #region Option BL
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries<Option>()
                                    .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                                                e.State == EntityState.Modified)
                                    .Select(e => e.Entity);
        // Add Default values when Creating or Editing an Entity
        string defaultvalue = "";
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entity.NoteInternal))
                entity.NoteInternal = defaultvalue;
        }
        #endregion

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

PS: does it make sense use the DYNAMIC datatype here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of three options:

1. Use reflection to check if each item has a `NoteInternal` property. This is slow.
2. Use `dynamic` to try to access the `NotIntenral` property of each item. You have to check for and handle the exception thrown when the entity does not have the property.
3. Make an interface `IHasNoteInternal` that defines the property and have all entities that has the property implement that interface. Then get all entries of `IHasNoteInternal` type.

I think that the 3. option is best and gives the best design, but it requires you to change the entities which migh or might not be possible. I don't know if you can use the generic `Entries<TEntity>()` method to get the changed entities - it might fail to match the entities based on an interface. In that case, use the non-generic `Entries()` and use linq's `OfType<T>()` operator to filter out the relevant entries.

```
var hasNotInternal = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                     .Select(e => e.Entity).OfType<IHasNotInternal>();
```

Comment: could you provide me a sample of code for Entries() and use linq's OfType<T>() ????

Answer (score 1):

Make your entries inherit from an interface that implements a NoteInternal property.

create an extension class

```
public static class DbChangeTrackerExtensions {
public static IEnumerable<T> TypedEntries<T>(this DbChangeTracker tracker) {
  return tracker.Entries().OfType<T>();
}
```

Then you can call it passing in this interface.

Or if changing the entities is not possible

```
var name="NoteInternal";

var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()  
                                .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added ||  
                                            e.State == EntityState.Modified)  
                                .Where(e => e.CurrentValues.Any(c=>c.Name==name && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)c.CurrentValue)));  
    // Add Default values when Creating or Editing an Entity  
    string defaultvalue = "";  
    foreach (var entity in entities)  
    {  
       entity.Property(name).CurrentValue=defaultvalue;
    }
```